# Бинарный поиск в "массиве отрезков"

Tags: c++, алгоритм, поиск

Задан упроядоченый vector из double, где каждый элемент представляет собой конец отрезка.
Например, {1,3,5,6,9} -- означает, что существуют следующие отрезки: [1;3], [3;5], [5;6], [6;9]. 
Массив вектор заранее отсортирован. Требуется для некоторого числа x найти индекс элемента начала отрезка, к которому принадлежит x. 
Как реализовать такой поиск (здесь ведь ищется не совпадение элемента, а принадлежность числа к диапазону)?

Answer (score 5):

Учитывая, что числа упорядочены и отрезки не перекрываются, достаточно рассмотреть 6 случаев.

1. x меньше самого первого элемента. за пределами
2. x больше самого последнего - за пределами.
3. x равно самому первому элементу. нужно подумать.
4. x равно самому последнему элементу. нужно подумать.
5. x находиться в диапазоне первого-последнего и при этом равен одному с элементов.
6. x находиться в диапазоне первого-последнего и при     этом не равен одному с элементов.

поэтому, алгоритм такой. Проверяем на вхождения в диапазон первый-последний и отсекаем первые 4 варианта. Потом применяем обычный бинарный поиск `std::lower_bound` и `std::upper_bound`. Если они равны - 5 случай. Если не равны - знаем границы (итераторами). `std::distance` поможет найти расстояние от начала (то есть, индекс).

На самом деле там нужен только один `std::lower_bound` + одно сравнение. Но для красоты объяснения было написано по другом.

Comment: Подойдет. Но если это тысяча, то моим способом за 10 сравнений, а линейно циклом - до тысячи. Выгода очевидна.

Comment: Не глянул в названия темы. Да и выгода действительно очевидна.

Answer (score 3):

Дополню ответ KoVadim небольшим кодом

```
std::vector<unsigned int> v = {1,3,5,7,9};

int to_find = 6;

auto it = std::upper_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), to_find);

int begin = *std::prev(it);
int last = *it;
```